# datatables serverside join in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I tried to combine the data using datatable serverside in codeigniter via ajax, But i get the error result, like this

> Message:  Call to a member function result() on boolean
>
> Filename: models/model_masterdata_menu.php
>
> Line Number:
>   66

```
private function _get_datatables_query()
            { //term is value of $_REQUEST['search']['value']
                $column_search = array('m.menu_id, m.menu_nama, m.menu_url, sm.statusmenu_nama');
                $column_order = array('m.menu_id, m.menu_nama, m.menu_url, sm.statusmenu_nama',NULL);
                $order = array('m.menu_id' => 'desc');
                $this->db->select('m.menu_id, m.menu_nama, m.mmenu_url, sm.statusmenu_nama');
                $this->db->from('menu as m');
                $this->db->join('status_menu sm', 'sm.statusmenu_id = m.statusmenu_id','left');
                $i = 0;

                foreach ($column_search as $item) // loop column
                {
                    if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
                    {

                        if($i===0) // first loop
                        {
                                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                        }

                        if(count($column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                            $this->db->group_end(); //close bracke
                 }

                 $i++;
             }
                if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
                {
                     $this->db->order_by($order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
                }
                else if(isset($this->order))
                {
                     /*$order = $this->order;*/
                     $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
                }

            }


            function get_datatables()
            {

              $this->_get_datatables_query();
                /*$this->_get_datatables_query();*/
              if($_POST['length'] != -1)
              $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);

                $result = $query->result(); # added

            }
```

what's wrong?
can anyone help me?

Comment: is this `foreach ($column_search as $item)` line 32?

Comment: @Jigar Shah, im sorry, After I check later i got error  Call to a member function result() on array

Comment: Just a top your classes and filenames should have only first letter upper case `Filename: models/Model_masterdata_menu.php` not `Filename: models/model_masterdata_menu.php` explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @wolfgang1983, same error no change

Comment: Only just a tip @muzamilindra

Comment: @wolfgang1983, thank you for your tips

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why it tells you `Call to a member function result() on boolean` because based on your code you didnt't even declare `$query` properly.

Anyway did you try something like that ?

```
function get_datatables()
{

    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)  $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ?   $query->result()    :   false;
}
```